# Get rows number based on criteria

Tags: excel, find, row

I have a table with a column (A) with a numeric value ("123") for some rows (not all of them) :

```
A     B
123 apple
0
123 pear
0
0
123 banana
```

In a 2nd table, I want to display only rows of the 1st table where there is 123 value.
I only want to display the first 5 rows.

```
123 apple
123 pear
123 banana
```

So, I can easily display this 2nd table if I have the rows number (with index(table1,RowX,colnum)).

But I really don't know where to begin to get these row number.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Just use a filter.  And if you only want the first five rows, either use the Advanced Filter or add a helper column with a running count of the instances of `123` and filter on that also for `<=5`

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out, by using a rank() on the first table... This works like a charm, without complex/heavy formula.